# Async button loading not waiting for all requests to finish

Tags: flutter, button, loading

I'm trying to build a button that shows a loading while doing api requests.

The function i'm calling to this button calls another function and that second function async request is not considered and flutter keeps running the code and does not await this.

This is what happends when the loading button is pressed

```
void doOnPressed() async
{
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    //await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {}); // This works

    await widget.onPressed!(); // This does not work

    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });
}
```

The function i want this button to await is a function called inside the widget.onPressed!() i think that's why this isn't working.

For example:

```
void action1()
{
   await action2();
}

Future<void> action2() async
{
   // await request // This is what gets skipped
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: post the real (not working) code of your `onPressed` callback

Comment: It's a lot of code, but i've tested this enough to be able to understand that the problem is in this specific step. I can make a real api call in the action2() function if it helps

Comment: if you `await` every `async` method it has to work just fine, you can have problems if you mix `await` with `Future.then` and other low level `Future` class api

Comment: `action1` (assuming it is marked `async`) cannot be properly `await`ed since it returns `void` instead of `Future<void>`.  Callers of `action1` therefore will not be able to wait for `action2` to complete.  If you cannot make `action1` return a `Future<void>`, please provide a minimal but complete example that demonstrates the problem and shows why you can't make it return a `Future`.

Comment: I realized the mistake. It was while passing the `onPressed` function to the button. I was just calling `() { action(); }` When i had to call it with async. `() async { await action(); }` and this fixed it.